# Python does not use the latest package

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am new to Python and have just installed Python 3.8. I am using package `openpyxl` to perform some excel related work. The following command in interactive terminal suggests that i am using version 2.1.4
`openpyxl.__version__`.
I would like to update the package to latest version for which i ran the following command (on mac) `pip3 install openpyxl` which indicates that version 3.0.2 has been installed.

However when I check the version on interactive terminal it still says version 2.1.4. How can I make python use the latest version of `openpyxl` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *interactive terminal* ? If this is the terminal within your IDE (eg PyCharm), it might be that you're using a virtual environment in which you have version 2.1.4 installed, while running `pip3 install openpyxl` on the *standard* terminal will install it on your base python installation. Try running `pip3 install --upgrade openpyxl` on the terminal which says version 2.1.4 is installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to close and open a new terminal? If you are using an old terminal this one won't be able to load the new version packages you've just installed.